# How to avoid dropping null values from dropduplicate function when passing single column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the below dataframe, from which I need to keep null values not being dropped from key column. I know that if we pass one more column then we can avoid dropping null values, but my problem is from key column I need to drop only the values which are duplicating, I should not drop null values.

```
id    pin    key  
-----------------
1       9       9
9       8       9
2       6       
6       3         
8       0       8

df.dropDuplicates("key").show()
```

I am getting output as below,

```
id    pin    key  
-----------------
1       9       9
2       6        
8       0       8
```

I am expecting

```
id    pin    key  
-----------------
1       9       9
2       6       
6       3         
8       0       8
```

If I use the above function it is dropping the null values also. Kindly provide me if I have any other alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that all the *empty values*, if the `key` column is `StringType`, `IntegerType` or *null values*, are considered *duplicates* and **only one row is shown in the output as original**.

What you can do in this case is to separate the *dataframe* into *two dataframes*, **one with all null or empty values in key column** and **another dataframe with not null values in key column**. Then apply the **dropDuplicates on the second dataframe** and finally **merge two dataframes**.

**Programmatically above explanation should be identical to below code**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val dfWithNull = df.filter(col("key").isNull || col("key") === "")
val dfWithoutNull = df.except(dfWithNull).dropDuplicates("key")

dfWithNull.union(dfWithoutNull).show(false)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Now i am able to show one null value in the output, but i have multiple nulls in the key column i want to show all of them..

Comment: I gess your key column in StringType is that correct? And the answer is not going to help you as even if you fill by 0 then all 0 will be considered duplciates and that was what happening in your case too. only one null was considered and all the rest as duplicates

Comment: for codes I woul need to know the datatype of key column.